# How to launch app on specific time in android OS?

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks

I'm looking for a way that I will set specific time in my android app (for example 9 p.m). I'll terminate the app and then it will launch again the app on 9 p.m and preform a specific method/operation and at the end close the app again.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to schedule to perform some business logic in the background, which does not require an UI to be displayed. In this case, you do not need to terminate and restart the app. A more trivial way is to make use of existing apis from Android SDK, below is the WorkManager that is released this year in Android jetpack which allows you to schedule a one-off task / repeated tasks with a relatively simple way.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics